# Qt5.5 32bit connection to MySQL database - limited User account

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm trying to establish a connection to my MySQL Server (currently running on localhost) via Qt5.5 (mingw4.92 32bit). I have found the qsqlmysql.dll and qsqlmysqld.dll in the mingw plugin directory, Qt gives the appropriate output that the drivers are available.
However, it is also telling me, that it can't be loaded. There are copiuos questions about exactly that problem, however, I am a bit lost. I can't do a lot on my laptop, since I have only limited user rights (it's a work computer).

What I have tried so far:

- Add the mingw plugin path to the build & run path setup in the projects manager
- Copy the libraries into my project folder and load them via code

I guess the solution is to build qt with mysql support, as suggested in many posts. But, lets assume you can't, because of UAC. How would you do it then? Btw, unfortunately my MySQL is 64bit.

On a side note: I find it very confusing that Qt does not support MySQL out of the box. Is there a particular reason to that?

Many thanks for any answer leading to a workable solution!

Comment: Qt supports a number of database drivers out of the box, including MySQL. Last time I checked there wasn't any need to do anything extra to get it to work.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't matter what you installation is, as the driver connects to the server through network, binary compatibility is not an issue.

Comment: Having limited user rights on a software development machine is in most cases highly counterproductive... You might wish to raise that issue at work, they are objectively losing money on that.

Comment: Not to mention how blatantly moronic UAC is - no option to write a config file for "trusted" applications, you have to click it every time like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you guys that uac and having a laptop that doesn't allow me to delete desktop icons is pretty moronic.

However, back to topic. I solved my problem by simply downloading the 32bit version of mySQL connector and put the container libmysql.lib and the debug version into my program folder and voilà: working with mySQL in qt is now a blast.

Thx a lot!